# How can I get the control that calls Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way at jJavascript runtime to return the control that called the `onchange` event?

Comment: what do you mean by "control"?? are you talking about the button, or the input or the select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose for some custom JavaScript to run when the onchange event fires for each control. Open a form to customize it > select a control > click properties. There is an "Events" tab where you can specify JavaScript functions to run when the onchange event fires for the control. One of the options for this event is "*Pass execution context as first parameter*". This means you could have a generic JavaScript function like so:

```
function control_onchange(context)
{
    // to get the control which caused the onchange event
    var control = context.getEventSource();
}
```

Therefore you could setup a control to call the function "control_onchange" and pass the execution context (which has useful information about the control) as the paramater.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334332.aspx) for the list of available actions with this context.

Some examples:

- To get the field name:

  ```
  context.getEventSource().getName();
  ```
- To get the field value:

  ```
  context.getEventSource().getValue();
  ```

Comment: +1 very nice, I wasn't aware of this member of the `context` "class".

Answer (score 0):

your onchangeevent the first variable will be the event with all relevant information including the element that triggered the event